# Mailchimp: Vague "Problem" in Confirmation Stage

Tags: mailchimp

After creating a Mailchimp campaign, in the final checklist to confirm details before sending, Mailchimp gives the message "Looks like there's a problem..." but gives no clue as to what the problem could be.

From reading online, it seems like normally in that situation, one of the sections listed will have a "Resolve" button rather than an "Edit" button, but that is not the case for me.

[image: Mailchimp screenshot showing warning message and nothing but gray "Edit" buttons next to the sections]

(Just off-screen is the "MonkeyRewards" section, also with an "Edit" button)

There's nothing I could find in the knowledge base, and of course, since I am using the free tier, there is no customer support to call (and it's not like I'm going to start paying for something that isn't working) so this is my last hope before I start looking for other services.